# How to sync pivot with extra field in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need some help about a problem in Laravel . I have 3 tables:

- pellets
- specie (there are the trees)
- specie_pellet (this is the pivot table)

The **specie_pellet** table is a pivot for the **composition of a pellet** and has an extra field called **percentuale** (percentage).
Obviously the relation is belongsToMany in Specie Class and belongsToMany in Pellet Class
In detail Pellet Class:

```
// Imposto la relazione con le Specie
public function specie()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Specie::class)->withPivot('percentuale');
}
```

In detail Specie Class:

```
// Imposto la relazione con i Pellets
public function pellets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Pellet::class)->withPivot('percentuale');
}
```

To modify the table i use a form:

```
{!! Form::model($pellet, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['composizione.update', $pellet->id]]) !!}
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <th>Specie</th>
    <th>Percentuale</th>
    <th>Azione</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($pellet->specie as $specie)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! Form::select('specie[]', $listaSpecie, $specie->id, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentuale[]" value="{{ $specie->pivot->percentuale }}">
            </td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url('composizione/pellet/elimina/id/' . $pellet->id . '/specie/' . $specie->id) }}">Elimina</a> </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! Form::submit('Aggiorna Composizione', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

the request pass to the route

```
Route::put('composizione/pellet/update/{id}', 'PelletController@updateComposizione')->name('composizione.update');
```

And finally I have the controller

```
public function updateComposizione(\App\Http\Requests\ComposizioneUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $pellet = Pellet::find($id);
    $specie = Input::get('specie');
    $percentuali = Input::get('percentuale');

    $pellet->specie()->sync([$specie => ['percentuale' => $percentuali]]);

    return redirect('admin/pellets/')->with('ok_success', 'Composizione aggiornata correttamente');
}
```

But I get this error: **Illegal offset type**

```
in PelletController.php line 94
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Illegal offset type', '/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/laraweb/app/Http/Controllers/PelletController.php', 94, array('request' => object(ComposizioneUpdateRequest), 'id' => '5', 'pellet' => object(Pellet), 'specie' => array('1', '7'), 'percentuali' => array('50', '50'))) in PelletController.php line 94
at PelletController->updateComposizione(object(ComposizioneUpdateRequest), '5')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(PelletController), 'updateComposizione'), array(object(ComposizioneUpdateRequest), 'id' => '5')) in Controller.php line 55
...
```

Can someone help me understand this please?
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english. I'm Italian ;)

Comment: `Form::select('specie[]'` means your select will put an array in the request. You should do `Form::select('specie'`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have specie[] because I have to pass multiple values. Example the pellet with Id 5 can have the specie with Id 1 and the percentage 50% but also can have the specie with Id 7 and the percentage 50%

Comment: You need to rethink your form.

Comment: Sorry apokryfos I am too intrusive if I ask you a help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you review the laravel tutorials on forms and rethink this approach, namely the select may not be the best way to do this. The select is not the best way to solve this one.

Try doing this:

```
@foreach($pellet->specie as $specie)
     {!! Form::open(["url" => "composizione/pellet/update/".$pellet->id, "method" => "PUT"]) !!}
     <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="specie" value={{$specie->id}} />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="percentuale" value="{{ $specie->pivot->percentuale }}">
        </td>
        <td><inpyt type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Elimina</a> </td>
    </tr>
   {!! Form::close() !}}
@endforeach
```

The rest would probably work. What's happening here is you're going to update a single `specie / percentuale` combination at once, not multiple ones.

Comment: thanks apokryfos now work but is not the right way for me because I need to update simultaneus all the composition of the pellet. When a user fill the form must update all the trees.

Comment: I have understand that the problem is the sync. If I set manually so: $pellet->specie()->sync([1 => ['percentuale' => 50], 7 => ['percentuale' => 50]]); it works right.

Comment: the sync so update the pellet with id 5 and witht the specie id 1 to percentuale 50 and also the pellet with id 5 with the specie id 7 to 50

Comment: I have found a mistake. I have resolved with an array_map ...thanks.